# spring-kafka how to run consumer in background

Tags: java, spring, junit, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I found a tutorial on spring-kafka where they created a producer and consumer. However, the program was run through a test case. As the test case ends, the consumer stops.

How to ensure the consumer keeps running in the backgorund so that I can test some messages from my terminal command line.

SpringKafkaExampleApplication.java

```
package com.howtoprogram.kafka;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringKafkaExampleApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringKafkaExampleApplication.class, 
        args);
    }
}
```

KafkaProducerConfig.java

```
package com.howtoprogram.kafka;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
        "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
        StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
        StringSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<String, String>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

KafkaConsumerConfig.java

```
package com.howtoprogram.kafka;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer;

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> propsMap = new HashMap<>();
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group1");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        return propsMap;
    }

    @Bean
    public Listener listener() {
        return new Listener();
    }
}
```

Listener.java

```
package com.howtoprogram.kafka;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;

public class Listener {

public final CountDownLatch countDownLatch1 = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = "topic1", group = "group1")
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
        System.out.println(record);
        countDownLatch1.countDown();
    }

}
```

SpringKafkaExampleApplicationTests.java

```
package com.howtoprogram.kafka;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.SendResult;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.rule.KafkaEmbedded;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureCallback;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringKafkaExampleApplicationTests {

@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
@Autowired
private Listener listener;

@Test
public void contextLoads() throws InterruptedException {

    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send("topic1", "ABC");
    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
            System.out.println("success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            System.out.println("failed");
        }
    });
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
    assertThat(this.listener.countDownLatch1.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();

}

}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

We run our Kafka application in a `while(true)` loop with an `@Scheduled` on a Spring Bean : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html
This way you can also delay the consumption of messages when the rest of your application is initialising.

```java
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 5000L, fixedDelay = 10000L)
public void process() {

  while (keepRunning) {
    try {
      ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(500);
      // do processing here
    }
  }
}
```

The `fixedDelay` is a bit strange. This value needs to be available, but is effectively ignored.

It might be tempting to start the consumer in the `@PostConstruct` but this way Spring keeps thinking the bean is in the init-phase. (so don't do this as Artem Bilan mentions below)

Comment: What you say must be done in the `Lifecycle.start()` and exactly not in the ` @PostConstruct`. That is fully bad to get access to the low-level resource and activate some processes when your application is still in the init phase.

Comment: @jvwilge I was doing the same thing. Then I found out about spring-kafka project., it provides some abstraction over the native kafka api.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your `main` after `SpringApplication.run()`:

```
System.out.println("Hit 'Enter' to terminate");
System.in.read();
ctx.close();
System.exit(0);
```

And your program won't exit until you hit the Enter button in console.

Comment: You also need `ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SpringKafkaExampleApplication.class, args);`. But this should not be necessary since the container is running in a non-daemon thread which will prevent the JVM from exiting.

Comment: @Artem as it turns out, adding listener.countDownLatch1.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); from the unit test after SpringApplication.run() did the job. However the tutorial said "_**For testing convenience, we added a CountDownLatch. This allows the POJO to signal that a message is received. This is something you are not likely to implement in a production application**_". Makes me wonder how we could run this on a production server. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try to run your application as a stand alone without any `context.close()` in the main?

Comment: Hey, it worked with just SpringApplication.run() as well. I must have been doing something wrong. But still, I'm confused how we could implement this app without the latch.